# Data in Vectors

Tags: c++, vector

I have 2 vectors both of different types i.e.

```
1. std::vector<project3::Vertex<VertexType, EdgeType>> Vertice2; //Contains a list of Vertices
2. std::vector<std::string>temp12;
```

My requirement is I want to store all the data from Vertice2 to temp12. Tried out a lot many different ways, but getting error. Even type casting didn't work out for me.

Latest I tried was `temp.assign(g1.Vertice2.begin(), g1.Vertice2.end());`

```
Error: 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::basic_string(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'project3::Vertex<VertexType,EdgeType>' to 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &'   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xmemory  208 1   Project_3_Revised
```

Comment: Is there a method available to convert an object of your `Vertex` type into a string?

Comment: they are different and *incompatible* types, what did you expect? The only way you will get this to work is if your `Vertex` class supports a `string` conversion operator.

Comment: What is the relationship between `project3::Vertex<VertexType, EdgeType>` and `std::string`? I.e., how is the former expected to be converted into the latter?

Comment: I have written a lot many methods which gives output based on std::string vector, but the vector should store the Vertices... I am not willing to modify everything in all the methods, so looking for a way around where I can store the data in Vertice2 to temp.

Comment: consider this - all your methods which work currently with the string vector, what do they do? Will they work better with the `Vertex` vector (i.e. avoid lots of conversions)? If so, does it not make sense from a design point of view to change your methods? Sometimes a large refactoring operation may look daunting, but the end result could be better/easier to maintain code!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a `vector` of apples that you're trying to store in a `vector` of oranges.  But apples aren't oranges, and that's your basic problem.

Either you need to make `temp` a `vector<Vertex...>`, or you need to convert each `Vertex` object to a `string`, and then store the resulting `string`s.  If you are trying to cram a Vertex in to a `vector<string>` without converting it, give it up.  You can't and should not even try to do this.  You're trying to put a battleship in to a pencil cup.

If you go with conversion, then using `std::transform` along with a conversion function of your own devising is a pretty straightforward way to do this.

Psudocode follows:

```
std::string ConvertVertexToString(const Vertex& vx)
{
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << vx.prop_a << " " << vx.prop_b;
  return ss.str();
}

int main()
{
  ...

  std::transform(Vertice2.begin(), Vertice2.end(), back_inserter(temp12), &ConvertVertexToString);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

C++ does not provide any default casts to std::string. C++'s templates are strongly typed, like the rest of the language.

You need to create a method or function to convert a project3:Vertex into a std::string.

Once you have that, you can use C++'s transform function.

`std::transform(Vertice2.begin(), Vertice2.end(), temp12.begin(), my_function_to_make_strings);`

Comment: I strongly suspect that one would want `std::back_inserter(temp12)` rather than `temp12.begin()`, as there's no indication that `temp12` isn't empty.

Comment: If you use `temp12.begin()`, `temp12` had better not be empty.  `std::back_inserter` is the way to go generally; if the profiler shows performance problems here, we've found that at least for simple types (including `string`), under visual studios, creating `temp12` with the size of the source vector, then passing `temp12.begin()` to `transform`, is slightly faster.

Comment: @James Kanze : Have you tried with VC++ 2010 yet? I suspect that `std::back_inserter` will be faster on any compiler with rvalue reference support.

Comment: @ildjarn You're right, I should has specified the version of the compiler as well.  Our tests were run with VS 2005.  Different compilers, or even different levels of optimization (we tried it with the max) may give different results.

Answer (score 1):

C++ does not support arbitrarily assigning objects of different types. In most cases casting won't work either and even if you force it to work (like a `<reinterpret_cast>`) it is not safe to do.

Your best option would be to use operator overloading and copy constructors to explicitly define the copying behavior you are expecting from your objects. For example, it is not clear when you assign a vertex to a string, what data elements should be copied.

Answer (score 1):

Your basic problem is that you have
`project3::Vertex<VertexType, EdgeType>`, and you want
`std::string`.  So how do you convert one to the other?

The usual solution for converting to a string of characters
(`std::string` or other) is to overload the `<<` operator.  So
you need first to define a function

```
std::ostream&
operator<<(std::ostream& dest,
           project3::Vertex<VertexType, EdgeType> const& value)
```

This will define what you data look like when converted to
a string.  Once you have that, something like:

```
std::transform(
    Vertice2.begin(), Vertice2.end(),
    std::back_inserter(temp12),
    (std::string (*)(
        project3::Vertex<VertexType, EdgeType> const&)) boost::lexical_cast);
```

should do the trick.